# xBox receiver code output is scrambled

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, shields, usb

I'm running the following code:

```
#include <XBOXRECV.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#endif

USB Usb;
XBOXRECV Xbox(&Usb);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); //halt
  }
  Serial.print(F("\r\nXbox Wireless Receiver Library Started"));

}

void loop() {
  Usb.Task();
  if (Xbox.XboxReceiverConnected) {
    if (Xbox.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) == 0) {
      Serial.print(Xbox.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
    }
   Serial.print("TEST");
  }
}
```

After running the example that the library includes and a spin off I wrote for test purposes I keep getting random output, this is just some of it:

> 9�]==�=�~=���y��:.�:�:����9�=��������:�:�\=���^=�?�}�:^���:�|]=9�\=*�*�������:�ܗ��.\�~=���

Comment: Have you changed the baudrate in the serial monitor to 115200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like wrong baud-rate. Change baud-rate in the Arduino IDE serial monitor.